# Load composer scripts inside class or function

Tags: php, composer-php

Im trying to load a composer script into my class or function. But keeps getting the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in
```

I have searched on Stack Overflow and Google and read something about namespaces? But how can I implement a composer script into a class or function?

function.php, loads the autoload.php script file:

```
 require(TEMPLATEPATH.'/vendor/autoload.php');
```

Custom function script:

```
function addToMailchimp($email) {


  use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;

  $MailChimp_api_key = get_field('mailchimp_api_key', 'option');
  $MailChimp_landings_page = get_field('mailchimp_landings_page', 'option');
  $MailChimp_landings_page_failed = get_field('mailchimp_landings_page_failed', 'option');
  $MailChimp = new MailChimp($MailChimp_api_key);

  if ($email != '') {

    $list_id = '06b233d443';

    $result = $MailChimp->post("lists/$list_id/members", [
        'email_address' => $email,
        'status'        => 'subscribed',
    ]);

    if ($result['detail'] == '') {
        header( 'Location: ' . $MailChimp_landings_page['url']);
        exit;
    } else {
        header( 'Location: ' . $MailChimp_landings_page_failed['url']);
        exit;
    }

  }

}
```

composer.json file:

```
 {
 "require": {
     "drewm/mailchimp-api": "^2.5",
     "mpdf/mpdf": "^8.0"
 },
 "autoload": {
     "psr-4": {
       "DrewM\\MailChimp\\":"src/"
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Autoloading would normally be setup on the initial page, most frequently in a front-controller or other .php file that is called first, and then organises what else happens. The 'use' statement also goes outside of the function, or class, and then the aliased class (here, `MailChimp`, is available within the whole file).

This code appears to be in a wordpress or older-style CMS system - it is possible to use composer within a plugin, or similar. There are examples of that around.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and readed into autoloading and psr-4. I have change my code structure and updated it above in my question.

Comment: `The 'use' statement also goes outside of the function, or class`